# Computing the cohomology group of CW-Complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I am stuck on the following problem from Lundell’s “Topology of CW Complexes”.

Let $X$ be a finite CW-Complex.  For every $i$, suppose that $dim_{F_p} H^i(X,F_p)$ is independent of the choice of the prime number $p$ ($F_p$ denotes the finite field).  Prove that $H^i (X,\mathbb{Z})$ are free for all $i$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers.

My problem is that I do not know how to do that considering the finite field.  Assuming that condition above, how can I prove that $H^i (X,\mathbb{Z})$ are free groups deriving from that?

Comment: Universal coefficient theorem?

Comment: The idea is to look at the cellular chain complex. Since $X$ is finite, this is bounded complex consisting of fintiely generated free modules. The assumptions on the torsion let you show that the components of the cellular boundary maps are either $1$s or $0$s. I quite like $\S$ 12.4 of tom Dieck book *Algebraic Topology* for some similar statements that would be helpful to look at.

Comment: @Tyrone.    Can you provide more elaboration?  How do you show such argument?

Comment: Have a look at the reference I gave you.