# Determine the cohomology of CW Complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

The following question is from Lundell’s book:

Let $X$ be a finite CW complex.  For every $i$, let us suppose that $dim_{F_p} H^i (X,F_p)$ is independent of the choice of prime number $p$, where $F_p$ denotes the finite field.  Prove that $H^i (X,Z)$ is free for all $i$, where $Z$ denotes the set of all integers.

Now, I know the universal coefficient theorem and cellular chain complex should be used,  but I am not sure how to progress the proof.  How can one prove the following using UCT and ccc.

Comment: This looks identical to your earlier question [Computing the cohomology group of CW-Complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660969/computing-the-cohomology-group-of-cw-complex)

Comment: This is exactly the same question as [your earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3660969/computing-the-cohomology-group-of-cw-complex). Instead of making a new post asking the same question, you should update and improve your earlier question by using the edit button.